# Extract all frames timestamps

Tags: timestamp, frame, ffprobe

My goal is to extract each frame timestamps of an video (it can be an mkv, mp4, avi, etc).
I parse the result in python, so I can map the frame 1 to 42 ms, frame 2 to 83 ms, etc...

I have tried these 2 commands:

```
ffprobe -select_streams 0 -show_entries packet=pts_time -print_format json VIDEO.mkv
```

```
ffprobe -select_streams 0 -show_entries frame=pts_time -print_format json VIDEO.mkv
```

They seems to always return me the same result, but the first one is faster. So, should I always use `packet=SOMETHING`?

Some video doesn't have `pts_time`. Should I use always `dts_time` or even `best_effort_timestamp_time` instead of `pts_time`?

Finally, the time from `pts_time`, `dts_time` and `best_effort_timestamp_time` seems to always be in seconds. Is there a way to get it in milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, frame timings are the correct attribute. It's possible but uncommon for multiple frames to be carried in one packet, or for a frame to be split (as slices) across multiple packets. But most of the time, you can use packet attributes.

The `*_time` fields are all printed as decimal seconds only. You can read the raw timestamps i.e. `pts`, but then you will have to multiple with the stream `time_base` x `1000` to get milliseconds.

Comment: Then, I guess I need to deal with the case where number of frame is different than the number of packet.
What do you think about this?

1. ``ffprobe -select_streams 0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames,nb_read_packets -count_frames -count_packets -print_format json VIDEO.mkv``

If ``nb_read_frames`` = ``nb_read_packets``, option 1, else option 2.

Comment: Option 1
1. ``ffprobe -select_streams 0 -show_entries packet=pts_time,dts_time -print_format json VIDEO.mkv``.
If the video has ``pts_time``, use it, if not, then use ``dts_time``

Option 2
``ffprobe -select_streams 0 -show_entries frame=best_effort_timestamp_time -print_format json VIDEO.mkv``

Comment: I was wondering what you think about my suggestion? Also, for the option 1, do I need to check if the flags is equals to ``D__`` ? More info about the ``D__`` flags  [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/2d9ed64859c9887d0504cd71dbd5b2c15e14251a/fftools/ffprobe.c#L2568-L2570) If yes, then I ignore that packet?